# iOS UITextFlied secureTextEntry not working on iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield, ios6.1

I have set a password field and under that a `UIButton` to toggle `secureTextEntry` to `YES`/`NO`.

The following is the code that I have used.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    [_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _password.secureTextEntry=YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)ShowPassword:(id)sender
{
    if ([_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"]])
    {
        [_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _password.secureTextEntry=NO;
    } else if ([_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_tick.png"]])
    {
        [_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _password.secureTextEntry=YES;
    }
}
```

The Above code seems to be **working** in **iOS7** and **iOS7.1**.

But in **iOS6.1**, The button image seems to be changing when clicked but the `secureTextEntry` works only once from `YES` to `NO`. Later if clicked only the `UIButton`, the image changes and `secureTextEntry` is **not working**.

It is not showing any warning or errors!

Comment: You are comparing `IUIImages`? Don't do that, use a boolean flag or just check `_password.secureTextEntry`. Also consider using a UISwitch` instead of a `UIButton`, it has a state. Also by convention method and variable names begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Ok I use Boolean flags. Thank you for the Info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable `UITextField` before set `secureTextEntry` value to `YES` in iOS6.

```
- (IBAction)ShowPassword:(id)sender
{
    if (_password.secureTextEntry)
    {
         [_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         _password.secureTextEntry = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        [_ShowPasswordButtonOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _password.enabled = NO;
        _password.secureTextEntry = YES;
        _password.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare images, in place of a boolean.

Comment: Ok. Disabling the `UITextField` worked. I was just wondering why this is an issue only in iOS6.1 and less as it was working fine in iOS7.0 and above.

Comment: @Zaph you are right, since the answer was not directly about that part, i didn't pay attention to it. Edited it now, thanks.